# Horizontal submenu with wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm using wordpress 3.4.1, and the headway theme. I'm not sure if headway is messing this up but I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

The basic request - a submenu that displays horizontally when hover or click on the main menu item.

Here's my html (the block ids and lots of code are inserted by headway):

```
<nav id="block-10" class="custom_YAP_menu block block-type-navigation block-fluid-height block-mirrored block-mirroring-10 block-original-97">
<div class="block-content">
<div class="nav-horizontal nav-align-center">
<ul id="menu-yap-menu" class="menu">

<li id="menu-item-750" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-750">
<a href="#" title="Solutions">Solutions</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li id="menu-item-764" class="nav2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-764">
<a href="http://youradminpro.com/business-solutions-2/business-solutions/">Business Solutions</a>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-780" class="nav2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-780">
<a href="http://youradminpro.com/pricing/">Pricing</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

here's the css:

```
body.custom #block-10 {position: relative; width: 100%;}

.block {-moz-box-sizing: float: left;}

menu, nav {display: block;}

.block-type-navigation li ul.sub-menu {left: -9999px; position: absolute; width: auto;
    z-index: 150;}

.block-type-navigation ul { display: inline-block; }

ol, ul {    list-style: none outside none;}

body.custom .block-type-navigation ul.sub-menu li a {margin: 5px 0 -5px -48px !important;     padding: 3px 0 30px; }

body.custom .block-type-navigation ul li a {margin: 0 -10px 0 -20px; }

.block-type-navigation li ul.sub-menu li a {-moz-box-sizing: border-box; max-width: 500px;
    min-width: 175px; width: auto; }

.block-type-navigation ul li a {display: block; white-space: nowrap; }
```

Inherited from: `ul.sub-menu ol, ul { list-style: none outside none; }`

I hope I copied everything you would need.
the site is:  youradminpro.com